# Flatlist with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uisearchbar

```
           <Search
              ref="search_box"
              onSearch={this.onSearch}
              backgroundColor="white"
              cancelButtonTextStyle={{ color: "red" }}
              placeholder="Search Food..."
              placeholderCollapsedMargin={wp("40%")}
              placeholderExpandedMargin={wp("7%")}
              searchIconCollapsedMargin={wp("45%")}
              inputHeight={hp("4%")}
            />
              <List>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Milk</Text>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Chicken</Text>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Rice</Text>
                </ListItem>
```

Hey everyone, I am using React Native with a class component and I was wondering how can I hide the list, and show it only when I tap on the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can defined a boolean variable and set it true when search text input focused,
like that

```
...
this.state = {
    showList: false,
}
...
return (
    <View>
      <SearchBar
        ...
        onFocus={() => setState({showList: true})}
      />
      {this.state.showList && (
         <FlatList
           ...
         />
      )}
    </View>
)
```

**here I supposed search component inherits the TextInput properties.**